# How to get Product Attribute at Order Success Page Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, attributes, orders

How can i get a Custom Attribute from an Ordered Product at the Order Success Page? I can load the Product Names but not the Attributes.

```
<?php
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $order = $objectManager->get('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->loadByIncrementId($block->getOrderId());
        $items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $alter = $item->getResource()->getAttribute('altersklasse')->getFrontend()->getValue($item);
            if ($alter == 18) {
                echo $item->getName();
            };
        }
?>
```

Comment: Share your code in question

Comment: I have add the code

Comment: let me know if you have any issue